# How To select first row per group with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the table named **DealOffers :**

[image: input table]

> I want to select only one record from each **group of dealIds** where
>   Price is **minimum**.

i.e : ***the expected output should be like this:***

[image]

Comment: Please tag the correct rdbms!!!

Comment: if you can write the actual result and not the image that would be very helpful.

Comment: Tag edited to sql server

Comment: can you please post data in normal format not in image format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. However, you should consider performance if you end up having to do this on a massive scale.

```
select *
from (
    select *,
        SeqNum = row_number() over(
            partition by DealId
            order by Price)
    from DealOffers) do
where do.SeqNum = 1;
```